# Is it possible to run tests programmatically on assembly in memory?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, xunit, vstest

**Scenario**

Dot net mutation tool that makes a mutation, runs tests, gathers results, and repeat like 2000 times. Mutations happen in memory, writing the mutated assembly to a disk for every mutation is very slow (at HDD's at least). The ideal world would allow for tests to be executed on an `Assembly` without them being written to the disk.

With that, running tests by calling 'vstest.console' or 'dotnet test' is not ideal because they call external executables and my tests are executed a lot of times for each mutation.

**Question**

- Given an `Assembly` is it possible to run unit tests (nunit,xunit,mstest) on it without writing it to a disk?
- Given a test project is it possible to run tests without an external executable to be called?

**Remarks**

- To my findings [vstest](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest) is only usable via an external process `IVsTestConsoleWrapper`.
- To my findings `dotnet test` uses vstest on the background.

**Stackoverflow**

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930714/is-it-possible-to-run-tests-on-an-in-memory-assembly) without real answers

Comment: Just create a RAM disk and store the assemblies there?

Comment: @Martheen that is a very interesting option to reduce disk write operation time!